# The error was:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, jython

i have to make a command line game that takes in monster1 and 2's Affinity|HP|AD and battles them while including the Affinity advantages, for example

If monster1's affinity is Earth and monster2's affinity is Fire than * monster1's AD by 20% per hit and lower monster2's AD by 20% per hit

```
def getmonsterData():

    global Affinity1
    global Affinity2
    global HP1
    global HP2
    global AD1
    global AD2
    monster1 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
    x = monster1.index('|')
    y = monster1.index('|',x+1)
    Affinity1 = monster1[:x]
    HP1 = monster1[x+1:y]
    AD1 = monster1[y+1:]
    printNow(Affinity1+"|"+HP1+"|"+AD1)

    monster2 =  raw_input("Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
    x = monster2.index('|')
    y = monster2.index('|',x+1)
    Affinity2 = monster2[:x]
    HP2 = monster2[x+1:y]
    AD2 = monster2[y+1:]
    printNow(Affinity2+"|"+HP2+"|"+AD2)
    battleNow();


def battleNow():

    global Affinity1
    global Affinity2
    global HP1
    global HP2
    global AD1
    global AD2
    if (Affinity1 == Affinity2):
       printNow("There are no affinity advantages in this battle")
    if (Affinity1 == ("Earth") and Affinity2 == ("Fire")):
       AD1 = (AD1*.20)+AD1  #THIS IS SUPPOSED TO RETURN AD1(MONSTER 1'S AD) TO THE INCREASED 20%
       printNow("Monster 1 has an affinity advantage over Monster 2")
       return
       printNow(AD1)
```

However, once i do this i get this annoying error

```
======= Loading Progam =======
Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> Earth|55|1
Earth|55|1
Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> Fire|52|1
Fire|52|1
The error was:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
Inappropriate argument type.
```

not sure where to go from this.. i've looked all over and no real solid answers that didnt have to do with multiplying a list.
help :D

EDIITTTTTT:
after changing my HP1/2 and AD1/2 to int(), i get no error but only recieve the output of

```
======= Loading Progam =======
Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> Earth|22|1
Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> Fire|25|1
Monster 1 has an affinity advantage over Monster 2
>>>
```

i don't get that last printNow(). i wanted to print the AD1 to see if the 20% increase was added to AD1 properly.

```
return
printNow(AD1)
```

Comment: **please** indent by more than 1 space! The standard is 4, and makes for much more readable code, and fewer errors.

Comment: not sure if i know what you mean? i'm new here. Just tried to space it out more for you

Comment: doing anything after a return is pointless - the return completes the function - and that function then exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to multiply a string by a float (AD1 * .20).

If you fire up the python interpreter, and do the following:

```
>>> ad = "10"
>>> print ad *.5 + ad
```

You'll get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

You want to convert AD1 to a float:

```
print float(ad) *.5 + float(ad)
```

Couple of other thoughts:

- Don't use globals.
- Use classes to store instance-specific data.
- Semicolons at the ends of lines are not necessary.
- Indent 4 spaces, as has been suggested

I played with your code a bit and came up with the following:

```
class Monster():
    """Define monster characteristics
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getMonsterData(self):
        monster =  raw_input("Enter the Monster's Affinity|HP|AD> ")
        self.loadMonsterData(monster)

    def loadMonsterData(self, monsterData):
        self.affinity, self.hp, self.ad = monsterData.split('|') # not safe
        print("{}|{}|{}".format(self.affinity, self.hp, self.ad))

def battleNow(monster1, monster2):
    """Make 2 monsters fight it out
    """
    if (monster1.affinity == monster2.affinity):
        printNow("There are no affinity advantages in this battle")
    if (monster1.affinity == "Earth" and monster2.affinity == "Fire"):
        ad = float(monster1.ad)
        monster1.ad = ad * .2 + ad #THIS IS SUPPOSED TO RETURN AD1(MONSTER 1'S AD) TO THE INCREASED 20%
        print("Monster 1 has an affinity advantage ({}) over Monster 2 ({})".format(monster1.ad, monster2.ad))
        return
    print(monster1.ad)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    monsters = []
    monsters.append(Monster())
    monsters.append(Monster())
    monsters[0].loadMonsterData("Earth|100|10")
    monsters[1].loadMonsterData("Fire|50|5")

    battleNow(monsters[0], monsters[1])
```

Comment: this is very confusing to me? when i load this into my Jython - JES envirement i get loads of syntax errors and when i fixed the things it asked me to i just get more errors saying 'monsters' isn't global.

Comment: Clearly you didn't fix anything if you get errors about anything being gloobal. The point of classes is that you can remove globals completedly.

Comment: we haven't used any classes with this programming course i'm in ITEC 109. We're writing in Jython, which doesn't use Classes, i got a syntax error because of the Class Monster..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because all your `HP`s and `AD`s are strings, not ints. When you multiply a string by an int, you get multiple copies of that string:

```
>>> "abc" * 3
abcabcabc
```

Since you can't logically multiply a string by 0.2, you get the error. To fix it, just use the built-in `int()` function like so:

```
HP1 = int(monster1[x+1:y])
```

As a side note, I'd like to introduce you to the `str.split()` function. Instead of calculating string indexes and trying to parse your input that way, simply do

```
Affinity1, HP1, AD1 = monster1.split("|")
```

and you're all set. Just call `int()` on the variables that require it before using them in any calculations.

Comment: after changing my AD's and HP's to int()'s(i didnt change affinity to int() because its still a str() because of Earth/Fire/Water) it worked down to printing out the affinity advantage but its not printing out the new AD of Monster1(AD1).   does AD1=(AD1*(.20))+AD1 suffice in adding the 20% increased int(AD)?

Comment: @Erik it should, and you don't even need the parentheses due to operator precedence.

Comment: yeah when i finish running this, i don't get an error but i only get the output of "======= Loading Progam =======
Enter the Monster 1's Affinity|HP|AD> Earth|22|1
Enter the Monster 2's Affinity|HP|AD> Fire|25|1
Monster 1 has an affinity advantage over Monster 2
>>> "

Comment: @ErikVorcov first, what does `printNow()` look like, and why did you make your own print function? Second, nothing will happen in a function after a `return` statement, so the final `printNow(AD1)` will never run.

Comment: @ErikVorcov thirdly, you can't print ints and strings together using the `+` operator for string concatenation, as you'll get an error, which I'm guessing may be getting swallowed by `printNow()`. Try running `print("|".join([str(x) for x in [Affinity1, HP1, AD1]]))` and see how that works